# Use of same javascript action for multiple id only differ in index number

Tags: javascript

I have a function which multiply two id-s and write it into a third id. I have to make it for all id.

So far I wrote this and it is working, but it would be really long at the end.

```
function () {
    var me1 = parseInt($('#me1').text());
    var ar1 = parseInt($('#td1').text());
    var sum1 = me1 * ar1;
    $('#re1').text(sum1);
    var me2 = parseInt($('#me2').text());
    var ar2 = parseInt($('#td2').text());
    var sum2 = me2 * ar2;
    $('#re2').text(sum2);
    var me3 = parseInt($('#me3').text());
    var ar3 = parseInt($('#td3').text());
    var sum3 = me3 * ar3;
    $('#re3').text(sum3);
}
```

I am looking for a solution where I can make the same action as the code above. I was thinking if I could change the numbers in the id to an array, but it didn't worked. See here:

```
function () {
    var idnum = ["1", "2", "3"];
    var me = parseInt($('#me' + idnum).text());
    var ar = parseInt($('#td' + idnum).text());
    var sum = me * ar;
    $('#re' + idnum).text(sum);
}
```

Comment: `$('#re1, #re2, #re3').text(sum);`

Comment: I guess u need to iterate the 2nd code in for loop. for id calculation and id storing

Comment: can you please provide the html code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over it like

```
function () {
    var idnum = ["1", "2", "3"];
    for(var i=0; i<idnum.length;i++){
        var me = parseInt($('#me' + idnum[i]).text());
        var ar = parseInt($('#td' + idnum[i]).text());
        var sum = me * ar;
        $('#re' + idnum[i]).text(sum);
    }
}
```

Additionally, if the number are always in sequence, you can get rid of the `idnum` array and just declare total number of elements like

```
function () {
    var total = 4; // total number of elements + 1
    for(var i=1; i<total;i++){
        var me = parseInt($('#me' + i).text());
        var ar = parseInt($('#td' + i).text());
        var sum = me * ar;
        $('#re' + i).text(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, the second one is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

In stead of using an ID selector (`#id`) you can use an attribute selector, which gives you more flexibility to search for an ID, for example:

```
$('[id^=me]').each(function() { // For each element having an ID that starts with 'me'
    var me = parseInt($(this).text()),
        nr = $(this).attr('id').split('me')[1]; // Fetch the 'nr' from each element
    var ar = parseInt($('#ar' + nr).text());
    $('#re' + nr).text(me * ar);
});
```

The `[attr^=val]` selector means that you search for all elements with an attribute called `attr`, and a value starting with `val`. More information about it can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Full example:

```js
$('[id^=me]').each(function() { // For each element having an ID that starts with 'me'
  var me = parseInt($(this).text()),
      nr = $(this).attr('id').split('me')[1]; // Fetch the 'nr' from each element
  var ar = parseInt($('#ar' + nr).text());
  $('#re' + nr).text(me * ar);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <span id="me1">2</span> * <span id="ar1">3</span> = <span id="re1">?</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span id="me2">4</span> * <span id="ar2">5</span> = <span id="re2">?</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span id="me3">6</span> * <span id="ar3">2</span> = <span id="re3">?</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span id="me4">8</span> * <span id="ar4">7</span> = <span id="re4">?</span>
</p>
<p>
    <span id="me5">9</span> * <span id="ar5">2</span> = <span id="re5">?</span>
</p>
```

---

Please note that this will also work for other IDs. So if you eventually add a 4th and 5th element, you don't have to update an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping once you have the Array ready. Try this:

```
function () {
    var idnum = ["1", "2", "3"];
    var me;
    var ar;
    var sum;

    // Loop here
    for(var i=0; i<idnum.length; i++){
        me = parseInt($('#me' + idnum[i]).text());
        ar = parseInt($('#td' + idnum[i]).text());
        sum = me * ar;
        $('#re' + idnum[i]).text(sum);
    }
}
```